# Can't find CD4050 library in Proteus 8?

Tags: ac, proteus, frequency-measurement

I am using this schematic as a frequency meter. I tried to search proteus libraries for this CMOS 'CD4050 , [IC3 in this schematic]' but all I've found is 4050 CMOS non-inverting buffer with one input and one ouput, I need this specific element with all the other pins of it, not the 4050 CMOS that proteus is showing, because the whole design of circuit counts on this element 'CD4050'. Any idea how to add this element to proteus ? Where can I find the library of this element. Please advise me ASAP. Thank you all. [image: Frequency Counter]

Comment: Because my eyesight is bad can you precisely show me on your schematic where IC3 is? Actually my eyesight is OK but because I can't see it on the schematic I'm beginning to have doubts. OK I've looked again and I'm pretty confident it's not there so I'm voting to close this question as being unclear.

Comment: Actually, that information **IS** in the schematic diagram - it's above the line connecting to the power input connector (right side of diagram) .

Comment: Sorry - above the line connecting to the INPUT connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked with Proteus but most electronic CAD packages have similar behavior when dealing with individual gates.

That is: each gate is individual. You place all of the individual gates in your schematic as required. Then you gather the gates into the desired packages.

My CAD package names this process as "packaging". You do this in the stage between completing the schematic diagram and starting to PCB layout.

Packaging assigns the individual gates to the physical chip.

The information about this process should be in the user manual for your particular CAD program.